# Net Core MVC Middleware does not work after publish

Tags: c#, .net, middleware, netcoreapp3.1

```
app.Use((context, next) => {
            // Ignore requests that don't point to static files.
            if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Cvler"))
            {
                
                if (context.User.Identities.Any(identity => identity.HasClaim("pozisyon", "admin")))
                {
                    return next();
                }

                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
            return next();
            // Stop processing the request and return a 401 response.

        });
```

Hi all, i want to hide CV folder from everyone except admin while development mode its working after publish middleware does not work everyone can see folder

Comment: i usually create a generic error handler middleware in the application. So i usually can throw an exception and catch it in error middleware and respond to the user with valid status. Also, double-check that you are not using static files middleware in your application, maybe it's conflicted with you middleware.

Comment: @AndreyRavkov thank you for you answer currently there is only one user which is admin and also i use app.usestaticfiles for caching jpegs etc. where should i keep cv folder to hide it from normal users

Comment: so, i suggest throwing unauthorized exception from you middleware, and then handle it in err middleware

Answer (score 0):

problem was i write app.usestaticfiles before middleware app.use